# explicit save in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

i have a Grid with Employee details (fullname, age, position) and a save button.
i want the Employee will be saved only when pressing the save button.
how can i implement it in MVVM ?

```
    <TextBlock
        Margin="3"
        Text="Full Name:"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
    <TextBox 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="3"
        Text="{Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        />     
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="3"
        Text="Age:"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
    <TextBox 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="3"
        Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        />
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="3"
        Text="Position:"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
    <TextBox 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="3"
        Text="{Binding Position, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        />


    <Button
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Content="Save"
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        Width="80"
        Height="22"
        Margin="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        />
```

my View model with not implemented Save method:
i'm not sure i know how to handle Explicit binding...

```
public string FullName
        {
            get { return _emp.FullName; }
            set 
            { 
                _emp.FullName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _emp.Age; }
            set 
            { 
                _emp.Age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }

        public string Position
        {
            get { return _emp.Position; }
            set 
            { 
                _emp.Position = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Position");
            }
        }


        public EmployeeViewModel(Employee emp)
        {
            _emp = emp;

            _employees = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>();

            if (_emp.Employees != null)
            {
                foreach (Employee employee in _emp.Employees)
                    _employees.Add(new EmployeeViewModel(employee));
            }
        }

        public string[] ValidatedProperties =
        {
            "FullName",
            "Age",
            "Position"
        };

        public RelayCommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _saveCommand ??
                    (_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(Save, CanSave));
            }
            set { _saveCommand = value; }
        }

        private bool CanSave()
        {
            foreach (string property in ValidatedProperties)
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValidationError(property)))
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        private void Save()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();    
        }
```

Comment: What are you using in regards to a `DataAccess` layer? Using `EntityFramework` model? or `SQL adapter`? Or Do you want a `List` or `Collection` of employees programmatically added to the Grid when the save command is clicked?

Comment: why do you use UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit?

Comment: simple List<Employee>

Comment: What do you mean `save`? Do you mean save from front-end to the `ViewModel` or to the database?

Comment: to the viewModel and eventually to the database (which in this case just a simple list in the memory)

Answer (score 0):

after some digging, i found some nice technique, using command parameter + converter.
http://www.shujaat.net/2011/01/updatesourcetrigger-explicit-for-mvvm.html

so in my case:

```
    <TextBlock
        Margin="3"
        Text="Full Name:"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
    <TextBox 
        x:Name="FullNameTextBox"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="3"
        Text="{Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        />     
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="3"
        Text="Age:"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
    <TextBox 
        x:Name="AgeTextBox"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="3"
        Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        />
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="3"
        Text="Position:"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
    <TextBox  
        x:Name="PositionTextBox"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="3"
        Text="{Binding Position, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        />


    <Button
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Content="Save"
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        Width="80"
        Height="22"
        Margin="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        >
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EmployeeConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="FullNameTextBox" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="AgeTextBox" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="PositionTextBox" Path="Text" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

changes to the viewModel:

```
private RelayCommand<object> _saveCommand;


public RelayCommand<object> SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _saveCommand ??
            (_saveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Save, CanSave));
    }
    set { _saveCommand = value; }
}

private bool CanSave(object value)
{
    foreach (string property in ValidatedProperties)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValidationError(property)))
            return false;

    return true;
}

private void Save(object value)
{
    string[] parameters = ((string)value).Split(new char[] { ':' });
    FullName = parameters[0];
    Age = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[1]);
    Position = parameters[2];
}
```

and little converter:

```
public class EmployeeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object [] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string fullName = (string)values[0];
        string age = (string)values[1];
        string position = (string)values[2];

        return string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", fullName, age, position);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```